# Column total NAN error

Tags: jquery, nan

I am using this bit of code to add the values in a table column which
works pretty well until it encounters a null td cell with a  
value.  From that point on in the loop, I receive a NaN error in my
alert.  I'm wondering how to ignore these non-numeric values or
replace them with zero for the calculation?

```
jQuery(function() {
        var MarketCapTotal = 0;
        // loop through the table
        jQuery('#grdWatchlistname tbody tr').each(function() {
        // replace the dollar signs and commas
        var MarketCap = (jQuery('td:nth-child(4)', jQuery(this)).html
().replace('$', '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ''));
            var td4th = jQuery('td:nth-child(4)', jQuery(this));
            MarketCapTotal += parseInt(MarketCap);
            alert(MarketCapTotal);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
MarketCapTotal += isNaN(MarketCap) ? 0: parseInt(MarketCap, 10);
```